# insert data from one table to two tables group by for Oracle

Tags: oracle, database-design, etl

I have a situation where I need a large amount of data (9+ billion per day) data being collected in a loading table that has fields like
-TABLE loader

```
first_seen,request,type,response,hits
1232036346,mydomain.com,A,203.11.12.1,200
1332036546,ogm.com,A,103.13.12.1,600
1432039646,mydomain.com,A,203.11.12.1,30
```

that need to split into two tables (de-duplicated)

-TABLE final

```
request,type,response,hitcount,id
mydomain.com,A,203.11.12.1,230,1
ogm.com,A,103.13.12.1,600,2
```

and 
-TABLE timestamps

```
id,times_seen
1,1232036346
2,1432036546
1,1432039646
```

I can create the schemas and do the select like

```
select request,type,response,sum(hitcount) from loader group by request,type,response;
```

get data into the final table.  for best performance I want to see if I can use "insert all" to move data from the loader to these two tables and perhaps use triggers in the database to try to achieve this.  Any ideas and recommendations on the best ways to solve this?

Comment: No answer yet on this one?

Comment: Just to be clear: you want one record per distinct REQUEST, including a  generated ID which you want to associate with each timestamp ?   Also: this table has fresh a set of data for each day.   If there is FINAL record for `mydomain.com` from yesterday what should be the ID for `mydomain.com`  *today* ?

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough detail.  the distinct record is from "request,type,response" tuple.  These should be distinct in the "final" table with the unique ID.  IF new records come in another batch for mydomain.com like "14330000000,mydomain.com,A,203.11.12.1,900" the total hitcount should increment for "id"=1 and a new row added to "timestamps" table with the timestamp 143300000000 correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

> "9+ billion per day"

That's more than just a large number of rows: that's a *huge* number, and it will require special engineering to handle it.

For starters, you don't just need INSERT statements.  The requirement to maintain the count for existing `(request,type,response)` tuples points to UPDATE too.  The need to generate and return a synthetic key is problematic in this scenario.  It rules out MERGE, the easiest way of implementing upserts (because the MERGE syntax doesn't support the RETURNING clause).

Beyond that, attempting to handle nine billion rows in a single transaction is a bad idea.  How long will it take to process?  What happens if it fails halfway through?  You need to define a more granular unit of work.

Although, that raises some business issues.  What do the users only want to see the whole picture, after the Close-Of-Day?  Or would they derive benefit from seeing Intra-day results?  If yes, how to distinguish Intra-day from Close-Of-Day results?  If no, how to hide partially processed results whilst the rest is still in flight?  Also, how soon after Close-Of-Day do they want to see those totals?

Then there are the architectural considerations.  These figure mean processing over one hundred thousand (one lakh) rows *every second*.  That requires serious crunch and expensive licensing  extras.  Obviously Enterprise Edition for parallel processing but also Partitioning and perhaps RAC options.

By now you should have an inkling why nobody answered your question straight-away.  This is a consultancy gig not a StackOverflow question.

But let's sketch a solution.

1. We must have continuous processing of incoming raw data.  So we stream records for loading into FINAL and TIMESTAMP tables alongside the LOADER table, which becomes an audit of the raw data (or else perhaps we get rid of the LOADER table altogether).
2. We need to batch the incoming records to leverage set-based operations.  Depending on the synthetic key implementation we should aim for pure SQL, otherwise Bulk PL/SQL.
3. Keeping the thing going is vital so we need to pay attention to Bulk Error Handling.
4. Ideally the target tables can be partitioned, so we can load into offline tables and use Partition Exchange to bring the cleaned data online.
5. For the synthetic key I would be tempted to use a hash key based on the `(request,type,response)` tuple rather than a sequence, as that would give us the option to load TIMESTAMP and FINAL independently.  (Collisions are extremely unlikely.)

Just to be clear, this is a bagatelle not a serious architecture.  You need to experiment and benchmark various approaches against realistic volumes of data on Production-equivalent hardware.

Comment: APC ! Agreed completely.  The plan is to load data in chunks of hourly or closer as necessary.  We have been testing this with Cloud like solutions (Netezza, Vertica and Hadoop flat files), but one of the customer's site has preferred oracle and has production support for RAC EE.

The use case for most lookups is to verify existence of a "request" within a timeframe.  Probably a 60 day window is good to keep data for.